# I am not able to scrape more than 10 results through selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, python-3.9

I am Web scraping through JD.com, but I think the site is dynamically loaded that's why it only generates first 10 results. I am posting code here, tell me what's wrong with it.

```
start_time = time.time()
url = "https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Stationery-Shops/nct-10453443"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(5) # Add a delay to let the page load

    
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.ID, "moreH").click()
    except:
        break

# Parse the resulting HTML with BeautifulSoup
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Extract the data you want from the parsed HTML
for i in soup.find_all("a", {"class": "resultbox_title_anchor"}):
    print(i.text)

print(time.time()-start_time)
```

Comment: "tell me what's wrong with it" - Invest a moment in observing the behaviour of the page in combination with your script - does it behave as you expect it to and if not, how does it deviate from how you would behave as a user to get more then 10 results?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, you're hitting the frontend pulling the first page of results over and over which is the reason you keep getting the same 10 results. I suggest hitting the ajax call to the feed which the frontend consumes -

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://www.justdial.com/api/resultsPageListing?searchReferer=gen%7Clst"

payload = json.dumps({
  "pg_no": 1,
  "median_latitude": "",
  "median_longitude": "",
  "city": "Pune",
  "search": "Stationery%20Shops",
  "area": "",
  "lat": "",
  "long": "",
  "national_catid": "10453443",
  "nextdocid": "",
  "stype": "category_list",
  "opt": "",
  "nearme": 0,
  "checkin": "",
  "checkout": "",
  "attribute_values": "%5B%7B%22e%22%3A100%2C%22v%22%3A%5B%22Distance%22%5D%7D%5D",
  "mncatname": "",
  "darea_flg": 0
})
headers = {
  'authority': 'www.justdial.com',
  'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'cookie': 'ppc=; scity=Pune; main_city=Pune; inweb_city=Pune; pincode=; alat=; alon=; sarea=; _ctok=6230f312d935116800969120694F8g4t4k6pkEFrDukjE4lx45t8xk3wzCk6o3; web_visit=2023-03-29T13:35:12.069Z; jd_www_nxt=1; rfr=gen; Continent=NA; Ak_City=POMPANOBEACH; bm_sz=5C2151CA67567E8C349FB0569BF17C74~YAAQLW4cuKSQChKHAQAAzGaULROK4glBUBWbqcYAgNUpGiv0mSs79xRAr1mIy08JANFeAhwr7Juv5XCrVDWLYcyXTK3dYsWQc3TiHLLaExs++WG/mmes2HwLcT1hllx1g7lNadtb3R/RMWUaAK7fJvrdOVRNHNKgagfxWipgtKCe/ejZPuA8XyZlABt8EOYKMJKJbjXFCiXz2t0zkx93phdgC5JxYvm9XOLczAPCQDGpYd007CemHHJ96OyW6IEWlOY+pkZVSXvK3Uhv8xf5KLR77cuTb14wDJ3VnNWfIAL4S3/JBA==~4276547~4277808; AKA_A2=A; _gid=GA1.2.1449457256.1680096913; _gat_gtag_UA_1220997_2=1; _gat_UA-1220997-15=1; _ga=GA1.1.201403875.1680096913; _abck=C89EED0C08C8DAD9A122742510F1B5A8~0~YAAQLW4cuLiQChKHAQAAHWyULQnVw8TPWZxKjDn0R04wS9iqjlHsRAi8uzfaI+Ft/YSUUFh/b/CWf4t4HMXjttDjLo9CqY2njYGOjoGbbfKQ26NLlgVR0bnOhZY+fVfI49li/FDDKrqA6uatwFvazQMslp/rw1bVaf/pIntD+gT7zyceok07bE8ubpR95QvqWLMcKv/qAmjK65IHMudr8tF8Uvhda0Rg0QjJjiMKRsseyLcpfJEUbv8UmL7yfULvvJJ8X4Yvb8sDrxet7XfEr+8MjSsQnh+X5A90Kj9+gVxpoSv4tAqUUmKb8LYCAh9aOQvaT8j5jME358q/M7Zvd/hXvrzN4KwkU1PTlOQchB2KeUsg9RNeG3B9OOUAYYHihe4TRZTCxVGTkKwevykNFISY6tf+ZWGkXTQ=~-1~||-1||~-1; TKY=408dd2855e26a420f5fdde41040f233e9ce884221c61f9ec3d9617d65a745279; bm_mi=C1D1B791E615FB4C4E43B58D422A28EC~YAAQLW4cuL2QChKHAQAAcGyULRO40QpYD7LcZfk780U7IaUZv0NP+oajAs2MSgnIwO+wbiGTdu0SL6w7ZdX0EXPQlEF7j7oh47jm9AL15q4Fs3DINR3ruY8Yh0klf5Qat1Kh0/jEVs7WkADfiiqI5MZJSv0aZh3O7Pe5NyO7Gbdb3ooUzE6EndI0GbUQFO73rVny8aW7f7zr92kcy5vXxsyei0Xg3G1Xo6plyvxB+Yf23cH4XIzrycX8mmJ97zkIMSYInSfI5nbE0t9l4zJnFbr2JNNXvLo5aul9lY43TYWWzKG7Bh7TPw+lhoMvU3zor0LHzoEt1j1rXGVWiUwDUn5At6SnCzM=~1; ak_bmsc=C88AF23C8C2373A98819808F151AEA11~000000000000000000000000000000~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; RT="z=1&dm=justdial.com&si=8e35bc78-0e6d-4b6e-8001-4f90c3ae124e&ss=lftqbkui&sl=1&tt=4lm&rl=1&ld=4lo"; lpg=lst; bm_sv=25E008ACF78491DA21F112816FE94C18~YAAQLW4cuGWRChKHAQAA2H6ULRMdn8eYhHf0KgC2On+eNui1nVjRWMmIy4ad1pUaiCVDn13o0p1tUxfTq6FnWpv/BqA9PXOlOApstUwjveuRIRG5AC2teYhlZETdTWF+LJ+Tq7ASBUavFdPGGUSnunTc3MwM/j4TKg0gVEM72D/7VRho0JJkdENVzfie4PJZmLUTuuQyH81sst5UrdlASthQPGTGbCKN3lH4WTO9OfVV4PcI3RVgoTda27SA371WPkg=~1; _ga_5PY4KYQRFS=GS1.1.1680096913.1.0.1680096918.55.0.0',
  'origin': 'https://www.justdial.com',
  'referer': 'https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Stationery-Shops/nct-10453443',
  'requesttime': '2023-29-3%209%3A35%3A19%20AM',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="110", "Not A(Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="110"',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  'securitytoken': '2a282a2b2a212b212b2d2921',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Here's the call the frontend makes, you can interact with this API directly you don't even need to "scrape" in a sense; just loop through a few pages by incrementing pg_no + 1 until you've maxed out the pages; the result comes already formatted and is very easy to work with.